# Inverse Laplace transform of two coupled equations in Mathematica

Tags: integral-transforms

I want to solve these coupled equations in Mathematica for F1(s) and F2(s) and the inverse Laplace of each of them to find c1(t) and c2(t).

[image]

[image]

the code I tried is:

```
{F1, F2} = {F1, F2} /. 
DSolve[{F1[
    s] == (C1[
       0] - (F2[s]*(Im[J/2] + g1*g2*\[CapitalLambda][s])))/(s + 
      g1^2*\[CapitalLambda][s]), 
  F2[s] == (C2[
       0] - (F1[s]*(Im[J/2] + g1*g2*\[CapitalLambda][s])))/(s + 
      g2^2*\[CapitalLambda][s])}, {F1, F2}, s] // FullSimplify // First
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Have you typed these into a Mathematica notebook yet? Please share your Mathematica code.

Comment: You are calling `DSolve` on Laplace equation??  Laplace equation is algebraic equation.

Comment: What is `J` in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
\[CapitalLambda][s] = 1/(s + \[Gamma]/2 + I*\[CapitalDelta]c);

 SOL = Solve[{F1[s] == (
 C1[0] - F2[s] (Im[J]/2 + g1 g2 \[CapitalLambda][s]))/(
 s + g1^2 \[CapitalLambda][s]), 
F2[s] == (C2[0] - F1[s] (Im[J]/2 + g1 g2 \[CapitalLambda][s]))/(
 s + g2^2 \[CapitalLambda][s])}, {F1[s], F2[s]}] // FullSimplify

c1[t] = InverseLaplaceTransform[F1[s] /. SOL, s, t]//ToRadicals(*Solution for c1[t]*)

(*Very large output*)

c2[t] = InverseLaplaceTransform[F2[s] /. SOL, s, t]//ToRadicals (*Solution for c2[t]*)

(*Very large output*)
```

Comment: Thank u, it was very helpful.